# Excel VBA adding date to cell doesnt use correct format

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

So, for my work im making an excel workbook - main idea is using a userform to add date to another (hidden) sheet.

In the form there are multiple textboxes - of interest is only one - Date.
Here is the code of my userform -

```
Private Sub CmdAdd_Click()
On Error Resume Next

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("WorkingSheet")
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    

    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Date                            'Adding today's Date
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cmbIDRequested.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtIDVisitor.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtVisitDate.Value           'The field im having troube with
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtCommentary.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Environ("Username")             'Adding user ID
    End With

    Me.cmbIDRequested.Value = ""
    Me.txtIDVisitor.Value = ""
    Me.txtVisitDate.Value = ""
    Me.txtCommentary.Value = ""

    ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub

Private Sub CmdClose_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub

    'Formatting entered data into usable date when user clicks away from the field
Private Sub txtVisitDate_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
On Error Resume Next
    
    If Not IsDate(txtVisitDate.Text) Then
        MsgBox "Enter Correct Date"
        Cancel = True
    End If
    
    Me.txtVisitDate = Format(CDate(txtVisitDate), "dd.mm.yyyy")

End Sub
```

Thing is - in my destination table date looks just like a normal date (for example - 20.07.2022). Ad if i click on the cell and then away - it properly formats it as date (changing it to whatever i want, like 20.07). But before i "update" the cell it acts like plain text. I set the whole column's fomat to Date, but im still having troubles with it.

Here is how it looks in the table:
[image]

first rows are the cells that i "updated" - double clicked on, then clicked away. You can see that they are formatted correctly because text is aligned to the right side. Bottom cell is plain text - and aligned to the left, like regular text does by default in excel

Comment: Welcome! What about [**DateValue(date)**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function)? I mean `.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = DateValue(Me.txtVisitDate.Value)`

Comment: Looks like that did it! Finally, date is formatted as actual date! Thanks a lot! (Im not sure if i can mark your answer as a "correct" answer if you answered in comments, so maybe make an actual answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you describe is correct. [**MS Help**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=TextBox.Value%20property) says:

[image: TextBox.Value Is A Text]

This means that if you assign this value to a spreadsheet cell, it will be written as a string.

*(The fact that after entering the editing mode and exiting it, the string automatically turns into a date is already a feature of Excel, and not the macro considered here)*

A direct solution to the problem would be to assign a value of [**type Date**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/date-data-type) to the cell. This can be done, for example, using the [**DateValue(date) function**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function)

```
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = DateValue(Me.txtVisitDate.Value)
```